# Parametrizing JUnit test with different data

Tags: java, web-applications, junit

I'm working on a Java webapp that might be causing me to misuse JUnit. I am building a multi-user interface for running JUnit tests. This is easy enough, but I can't figure out a way to indicate that User A wants to parametrize a JUnit test class with data X, and User B wants to parametrize with data Y.

Is this even possible? If not,  I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: A test case factory that takes `User X` as input and returns the correct parameterized type instace?

Comment: @vikingsteve I'm not quite sure what you mean by test case factory. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

How about using `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` and `@Parameters`?

You should be able to run the same tests using data for different users, specifying different data sets in a method tagged with `@Parameters`that returns a `Collection` that gets passed to the Test class constructor.

See http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/

Comment: Thanks, but this leaves me with the same problem. How do I tell the @Parameters method which data to use? Any way I can think of presents me with synchronization problems.

Comment: What kind of synchronization problems are you facing? Ideally, unit tests should not have any dependencies or interactions with objects "outside" the scope of the test, so running the same test more than once at a time shouldn't cause issues.

Comment: Once the unit tests are running everything is fine. Synchronization problems occur when trying to indicate to @Parameters which data to use. Multiple requests could be received at a time, and it sucks to have to do thread handling for the sake of passing an argument.

Comment: Stated this way, it seems to me that what you actually want to achieve is two different test suites, that actually consist of the same tests ran against two different sets of data, but conceptually look, to me, like two completely different test suites.
If you built it this way, you could have different requests execute different `@Test`-annotated classes that instantiate the test object with different values and execute its test methods. Not sure if this makes sense to you, though.

Comment: Yeah that makes perfect sense, the problem is though, that I want the user to be able to specify data dynamically. I appreciate your input. It seems that I am indeed misusing JUnit.

Comment: BTW, how are your executing your tests anyway? I mean, how are they sending requests to execute test?

Comment: I have a Servlet that handles requests by getting the test class name to be run, and the accompanying data. Then JUnitCore's run() is used with that data. I can get the data into the test class by setting a static variable and reading from that in an @BeforeClass method, but of course this is problematic.

Comment: The thing is, I don't see a reason why you should want to have a Servlet accessible via HTTP that runs your tests. How about moving them to a build process executed, for instance, with Maven and ran by a CI server like Jenkins/Hudson?

Comment: I am trying to convert an existing JUnit test suite meant for developers into something that can be used by non-developers

Comment: Then probably using something like Jenkins as a frontend is the solution you're looking for